# Which are the best Thai amulets for love, job, and career?

Tags: thai

Which are the best Thai amulets that can help to get my love back, and also help in my life, jobs, and career?

Comment: Not sure this is related to Buddhism

Comment: @Sankha Kulathantille It's Buddhism but is it the teaching of the Buddha?

Comment: Definitely isn't the word of the Buddha or Ariya Sangha! "amulets that can help to get my love back" sounds more like witchcraft! :)

Answer (score 2):

Experts believe as recent as 500 years ago around south east Asia region), texts were generated about a story of King Kosala asking Buddha about anisong (good karma) for creating Buddha's image.  Some Thai Buddhist temples create amulets ever since.

If you still want to have one, just don't spend tons of money on it. Amulets are collectible just like baseball cards.  There are tons of forgery.  You may go to Thai buddhist temple near you and ask a monk for one.  Or if you live in the US, you can try writing Metta Forest Monastery in CA,and ask for one if they still have any.  [wat metta](http://www.watmetta.org/photoPageAmulets2014.html)

PS.  there is no way of measuring "mystical" power of an amulet, so pick one that appeals to you.  This sutta might help you further causes in love and career.  Buddha gave this lecture to the Direction Worshipers...

[Sigalovada Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.ksw0.html)

As an employee

- start work before boss
- leave work after boss
- taking only what is given
- doing assigned work well
- promoting boss' good reputation.

and if you are the boss

- allocating work according to aptitude
- providing wages
- looking after the sick
- sharing special treats (bonus)
- giving reasonable time off work

As a friend (so you will be well loved)

- generosity
- kind words
- acting for their welfare
- impartiality
- honesty

These will help us more than any amulets could.

Comment: +1 but I wouldn't mind if you also added any reference or citation for the opening sentence.

Comment: u bet.. since it's border line a sutta and folk legend, i will do  my best to find official account in English.   i might have heard it from a monk in person long time ago.  I'm sure you are aware that consecrating an object is one of the low arts Buddha prohibits Bhikku to do but they are doing it in some monasteries.  It is a sensitive subject.

Comment: it was anything's being "added to the pali canon" as recently as 500 years ago that was news to me.

Comment: Similar story of anisong of building Buddha's image first appeared (in written format) in Pannasa Jataka.   unfortunately i could not find online book. https://store.pariyatti.org/Pannasa-Jataka-Vol-1-Stories-1-25_p_2119.html Only hard copy available.  Stories are copied and modified into  Lan Na Canon (written format in 1824), which was rejected by King of Siam Tripitaka in  1893.  However, Thai tradition is still creating Buddha amulets til today.    I know it's a crude research paper but something to back up my statement.

Comment: For extra credit, one of Buddha's earliest image , appeared on the coin of emperor  Kanishka I, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanishka  120AD  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanishka#/media/File:Coin_of_Kanishka_I.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Here is Buddha's take on what the translator pinned as 'protective charms & ceremonies'

> "Endowed with these five qualities, a lay follower is an outcaste of a lay follower, a stain of a lay follower, a dregs of a lay follower. Which five? He/she does not have conviction [in the Buddha's Awakening]; is unvirtuous; is eager for protective charms & ceremonies; **trusts protective charms & ceremonies**, not kamma; and searches for recipients of his/her offerings outside [of the Sangha], and gives offerings there first. Endowed with these five qualities, a lay follower is an outcaste of a lay follower, a stain of a lay follower, a dregs of a lay follower.
>
> "Endowed with these five qualities, a lay follower is a jewel of a lay follower, a lotus of a lay follower, a fine flower of a lay follower. Which five? He/she has conviction; is virtuous; **is not eager for protective charms & ceremonies**; trusts kamma, not protective charms & ceremonies; does not search for recipients of his/her offerings outside [of the Sangha], and gives offerings here first. Endowed with these five qualities, a lay follower is a jewel of a lay follower, a lotus of a lay follower, a fine flower of a lay follower."
> [AN 5.175](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/AN/AN5_175.html)

Answer (score 0):

The quote from [DN 2](https://suttacentral.net/dn2/en/sujato) below shows practices which are considered wrong livelihood for monks and contemplatives.

While the making of amulets and talismans is not listed explicitly, "casting spells for good or bad luck" is listed, which is close enough.

Furthermore, such luck amulets go along with practices like astrology, palmistry, geomancy, omen-reading, dream-interpretation, protection spells or charms and so on, which are all considered wrong livelihood for monks and contemplatives.

On the other hand, the practice of loving kindness (*metta*) might give you the Buddhist version of good luck with these 11 benefits:

> "One sleeps easily, wakes easily, dreams no evil dreams. One is dear
> to human beings, dear to non-human beings. The devas protect one.
> Neither fire, poison, nor weapons can touch one. One's mind gains
> concentration quickly. One's complexion is bright. One dies unconfused
> and — if penetrating no higher — is headed for the Brahma worlds.
> [AN 11.16](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an11/an11.016.than.html)

Wrong livelihood for monks and contemplatives:

> There are some ascetics and brahmins who, while enjoying food given in
> faith, still earn a living by unworthy branches of knowledge, by wrong
> livelihood. This includes such fields as limb-reading, omenology,
> divining celestial portents, interpreting dreams, divining bodily
> marks, divining holes in cloth gnawed by mice, fire offerings, ladle
> offerings, offerings of husks, rice powder, rice, ghee, or oil;
> offerings from the mouth, blood sacrifices, palmistry; geomancy for
> building sites, fields, and cemeteries; exorcisms, earth magic, snake
> charming, poisons; the crafts of the scorpion, the rat, the bird, and
> the crow; prophesying life span, chanting for protection, and animal
> cries. They refrain from such unworthy branches of knowledge, such
> wrong livelihood. This pertains to their ethics.
>
> There are some ascetics and brahmins who, while enjoying food given in
> faith, still earn a living by unworthy branches of knowledge, by wrong
> livelihood. This includes reading the marks of gems, cloth, clubs,
> swords, spears, arrows, weapons, women, men, boys, girls, male and
> female bondservants, elephants, horses, buffaloes, bulls, cows, goats,
> rams, chickens, quails, monitor lizards, rabbits, tortoises, or deer.
> They refrain from such unworthy branches of knowledge, such wrong
> livelihood. This pertains to their ethics.
>
> There are some ascetics and brahmins who, while enjoying food given in
> faith, still earn a living by unworthy branches of knowledge, by wrong
> livelihood. This includes making predictions that the king will march
> forth or march back; or that our king will attack and the enemy king
> will retreat, or vice versa; or that our king will triumph and the
> enemy king will be defeated, or vice versa; and so there will be
> victory for one and defeat for the other. They refrain from such
> unworthy branches of knowledge, such wrong livelihood. This pertains
> to their ethics.
>
> There are some ascetics and brahmins who, while enjoying food given in
> faith, still earn a living by unworthy branches of knowledge, by wrong
> livelihood. This includes making predictions that there will be an
> eclipse of the moon, or sun, or stars; that the sun, moon, and stars
> will be in conjunction or in opposition; that there will be a meteor
> shower, a fiery sky, an earthquake, thunder; that there will be a
> rising, a setting, a darkening, a brightening of the moon, sun, and
> stars. And it also includes making predictions about the results of
> all such phenomena. They refrain from such unworthy branches of
> knowledge, such wrong livelihood. This pertains to their ethics.
>
> There are some ascetics and brahmins who, while enjoying food given in
> faith, still earn a living by unworthy branches of knowledge, by wrong
> livelihood. This includes predicting whether there will be plenty of
> rain or drought; plenty to eat or famine; an abundant harvest or a bad
> harvest; security or peril; sickness or health. It also includes such
> occupations as computing, accounting, calculating, poetry, and
> cosmology. They refrain from such unworthy branches of knowledge, such
> wrong livelihood. This pertains to their ethics.
>
> There are some ascetics and brahmins who, while enjoying food given in
> faith, still earn a living by unworthy branches of knowledge, by wrong
> livelihood. This includes making arrangements for giving and taking in
> marriage; for engagement and divorce; and for scattering rice inwards
> or outwards at the wedding ceremony. It also includes **casting spells
> for good or bad luck**, curses to prevent conception, bind the tongue,
> or lock the jaws; charms for the hands and ears; questioning a mirror,
> a girl, or a god as an oracle; worshiping the sun, worshiping the
> Great One, breathing fire, and invoking Siri, the goddess of luck.
> They refrain from such unworthy branches of knowledge, such wrong
> livelihood. This pertains to their ethics.
>
> There are some ascetics and brahmins who, while enjoying food given in
> faith, still earn a living by unworthy branches of knowledge, by wrong
> livelihood. This includes rites for propitiation, for granting wishes,
> for ghosts, for the earth, for rain, for property settlement, and for
> preparing and consecrating house sites, and rites involving rinsing
> and bathing, and oblations. It also includes administering emetics,
> purgatives, expectorants, and phlegmagogues; administering ear-oils,
> eye restoratives, nasal medicine, ointments, and counter-ointments;
> surgery with needle and scalpel, treating children, prescribing root
> medicines, and binding on herbs. They refrain from such unworthy
> branches of knowledge, such wrong livelihood. This pertains to their
> ethics.
>
> [DN 2](https://suttacentral.net/dn2/en/sujato)